# How to bind variable using prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a table in html where the user can click on a row and the data-attribute for that row is passed to the a PHP file which is loaded on the screen. I would like this PHP file to include some data related to the variable that was passed.

For example, here is the simple jQuery that defines the variable:

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-recordId");
    $('#section2').load('data_entry_form.php?id='+id);
});
```

And here is the PHP that is intended to USE the id variable and fetch associated elements (as per the SQL query) where the id is = to the fee_source_id. **What is wrong with the PHP? it's not working.** I would like to simply echo/show the result of the SQL query where the condition `fee_source_id = :id` is true.

```
<html>
<form>
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sth = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date
    FROM  a_aif
    WHERE a_aif.fee_source_id = :id');
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

?>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what does it mean? You are building a SELECT query, but not doing anything with the results... Edit: And you have a *syntax error* in your query, remove the `,` before `FROM`.

Comment: @NullPointer I am aware of PDO and connecting to the db...

Comment: @DCoder I have updated the Question to show you what I am trying to do with the result... simply echo the result.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that *that* is the way to get results from the database? The link NullPointer posted is more than just "use PDO", it contains a tutorial on how to select data properly. See also [this PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [**fetch**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) the row of the result set. Then echo the fields you require .

It may help if you use  [**$.getJSON**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of $('#section2').load if you are returning the array

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('
        SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
          a_aif.fee_source_id,
          a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
          a_aif.document_filing_date
        FROM  a_aif
        WHERE a_aif.fee_source_id = :id');
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sth->execute();
    $row  = $sth-> fetch(); // returns 1 row
    //$data[] = $row; Returns all of array 
    //$id = $row['id'];// Returns indivadual fiels in array

    echo $data;
```